# How do I distinguish between source and target nodes by edges in large graphs?

Tags: edges, graph-visualization, gephi

The arrowhead loses significance in a directed graph with many nodes and edges. Is there a way to give two colors to each edge, one near target node and one near source node so it's easier to see edge direction?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> "*The arrowhead loses significance* …"

Curve orientation indicates direction already (upward curve connects source to target from left to right, downward curve from right to left). Enlarging arrow size makes it easier to see edge source (side without arrow):

Preview > Preview Settings > Settings > Edge Arrows > Size

> "*Is there a way to give two colors to each edge, one near target node and one near source node* …"

No. Edges can however be colored according to source *or* target:

Preview > Preview Settings > Settings > Edges > Colors > (Source/Target)